# SQL group function for multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I really need help with this question.

Given an instance of two relations, what is the result of the query? I know the answer, I just need to know how you get it? I'm really confused regarding the `GROUP` line.

Relation R (A, B):

```
1  2
3  4
1  3
```

Relation S (B, C):

```
1  3
2  4
```

Query:

```
SELECT R.A, avg(R.B) as av
FROM R, S
WHERE R.B < 4
GROUP BY R.A, S.C
HAVING max(S.B) >= 2
```

Answer is:

```
A   Av
1   2.5
```

Comment: Yes i know the answer, it is 

A = 1 
AV = 2.5

Comment: Im sorry, R refers to the first relation and S to the second.

Comment: Normally you'd provide a *question* and we the answer. Seems like you got that backwards ...

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting R.A where R.B < 4.  There are two qualifying records, and they both have a value of 1.

You are doing a cartesian join between R and S, but not selecting anything from S, so anything to do with S is irrelevent.

Back to R, the two values of B that are less than 4 are 2 and 3.  The average of these two numbers is 2.5.

The fact that you are grouping by S.C without selecting it should cause your query to crash.

Comment: Thats what i thought too. However when i punched in the database the result did indeed pop out. As well, my professor said this was the correct answer. So im really confused at this point ahah

Comment: I had a similar thought, but the reason why it works is that S.C is still available to -- and being considered by -- the server, just eliminated from the result set... you can `GROUP BY` something not selected much the same way as you can `ORDER BY` something not selected... it's just that the former isn't something you would ordinarily have a reason to do in practice.

Comment: haha yes i figured so. Happens to be a really tricky question

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT R.A, R.B
FROM RelationR AS r
LEFT JOIN RelationS AS s ON r.b = s.b
```

It gives you:

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
```

Then, you just need to group be only `A` like this:

```
SELECT 
  R.A, 
  AVG(R.B) * 1.0    AS av
FROM RelationR      AS R
LEFT JOIN RelationS AS S ON R.B = S.B
WHERE R.B < 4
GROUP BY R.A
HAVING MAX(S.B) >= 2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e1f6/4)

This will give you:

```
| A |  AV |
-----------
| 1 | 2.5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0899d/9) demo, it runs your statement in few steps.

First, this one

```
SELECT R.A, R.B, S.B AS sb, S.C
FROM R, S
ORDER BY R.A, S.C
```

which gives you:

```
A   B   SB  C
1   2   1   3
1   3   1   3
1   2   2   4
1   3   2   4
3   4   1   3
3   4   2   4
```

Then run it with `WHERE` constraint:

```
SELECT R.A, R.B, S.B AS sb, S.C
FROM R, S
WHERE R.B < 4
ORDER BY R.A, S.C
```

which gives:

```
A   B   SB  C
1   2   1   3
1   3   1   3
1   2   2   4
1   3   2   4
```

Then run this via `GROUP BY`. Normally, you can only use columns that are mentioned in `GROUP BY` or other columns, but only in aggregate functions like `avg` or `max` (but MySQL is forgiving, that's why used PostgreSQL server in this example for better compatibility with SQL92):

```
SELECT R.A, avg(R.B) AS av, S.C, max(S.B) AS maxsb
FROM R, S
WHERE R.B < 4
GROUP BY R.A, S.C
```

which yields:

```
A   AV  C   MAXSB
1   2.5     3   1
1   2.5     4   2
```

Add `HAVING` clause (and keep only one line of previous result):

```
SELECT R.A, avg(R.B) as av, S.C, max(S.B) AS maxsb
FROM R, S
WHERE R.B < 4
GROUP BY R.A, S.C
HAVING max(S.B) >= 2
```

which produces:

```
A   AV  C   MAXSB
1   2.5     4   2
```

Finally, you drop unused columns in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT R.A, avg(R.B) as av
FROM R, S
WHERE R.B < 4
GROUP BY R.A, S.C
HAVING max(S.B) >= 2
```

and get:

```
A   AV
1   2.5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Note that you should accept and/or upvote questions that helped you solve the problem or if you like them - this is how this site works. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/about)